# How to find the difference between rows of cumulative counts while retaining columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have the following data:

```
machine_id  time_to_failure
430494        1000
430494        700
430494        500
430494        100
430495        1000
430495        200
```

The time to failure data is counted from a reference day 0 and I would like to turn it into the time since the previous failure:

```
machine_id  time_to_failure
430494        300
430494        200
430494        400
430494        100
430495        800
430495        200
```

I tried using groupby and pivoting duplicate rows into new columns for the subtraction. However, I would like to do it in place to preserve other columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try with `groupby().diff()`:

```
df['time_to_failure'] = (df.groupby('machine_id')
                            ['time_to_failure'].diff(-1)
                           .fillna(df['time_to_failure'])
                        )
```

Output:

```
   machine_id  time_to_failure
0      430494            300.0
1      430494            200.0
2      430494            400.0
3      430494            100.0
4      430495            800.0
5      430495            200.0
```

Comment: Error: "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis". It is due to me using groupby on multiple columns? Error is from the fillna line

Comment: Is `machine_id` the index of your data?

Comment: It's a column of data

Comment: Can't think of any other reason. It works for the sample data. Also check your index for duplicates.

Comment: Fixed it! I needed to reset the index when concatenating. Thanks!